# Swagger @ApiResponse should show List of ErrorObject i.e List<MyErrorObject> ? How is this possible?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox, springfox-boot-starter

The swagger version I am using is as below and **My question is related to the @ApiResponse annotation**.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When a user accesses my api and if the user provides invalid details/input, my application is returning a list of errors in the users input.
Each error is captured in a an error object

```
MyErrorObject 
{
  Date date;
  String errorCode;
  String errorMessage;
  //getters //setters
}
```

-so my application response incase of invalid user input will look something like below -

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-09-22",
        "errorCode": "6548",
        "errorMessage": "there are no booking available in selected city"
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-22",
        "errorCode": "2649",
        "errorMessage": "your age does not allow you to travel to this location"
    }
]
```

**---Now back to my question -** using swagger @ApiResponse annotation, I want the api users to know the response format. So, I tried below

```
@ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
          message = ErrorConstants.NotAllowed, response=List<MyErrorObject>.class)
```

But above did not work, I am seeing below compile time error -

> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MemberValueArrayInitializer

I tried - other combinations too like below but no luck -

```
@ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
          message = ErrorConstants.NotAllowed, response=List<MyErrorObject.class>)
```

**So, what is the right way to represent a list of errors using @ApiResponse annotation??**
So the error response on swagger doc looks something like below -

```
[
 {
  "date": "Date",
  "errorCode": "string",
  "errorMessage": "string"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the [`ApiResponse.class`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/1.5/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.java), it's evident they have a [`responseContianer`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/1.5/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.java#L87) attribute that you can set to achieve the desired result.

```java
@ApiResponse(
    code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
    message = ErrorConstants.NotAllowed, 
    response = MyErrorObject.class,
    responseContainer = "List"
)
```

Comment: Quite great solution. I looked at [ApiResponse](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/index.html?com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.html) and this property is not in the docs. Thanks for digging deeper in to source code. +1. If you like the Q can you upvote it.